# How to perform a connectivity check without HTTP

Tags: c++, yocto, connman

At the moment our IOT device use the connman for our network connection. Connman periodically makes a connectivity check over HTTP. Now, we are not allowed to use HTTP anymore.

Do you have any advice on how to perform connectivity checks? We need to distinguish between "network connected" and "online". Are there any services for that? Best practices?

Comment: The only way to check if you are "online" is to attempt to connect to an actual online server and see if it succeeds or fails. You don't need HTTP for that, TCP will suffice (HTTP runs on top of TCP).

Comment: Yes. One of the problem is, that we need a world wide functioning solution. We thought about HTTP, because it looks like, "every one" is doing it with HTTP (Android, Connman, Apple). We also thought about ping (ICMP), but as far as I know, ping is often blocked.

Comment: since HTTP runs on top of TCP, you can connect to any public HTTP server using a simple TCP socket without actually sending any HTTP request.